# Set dataframe cell value based on condition and column day_of_week

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the column *names* are datetimes. I want to update the rows where the cell values are NaN and the dayofweek is Friday or Saturday.

This

```
        20191114  20191115 20191116 20191117 20191118
    1     nan        nan      nan     nan      nan
    2     nan        5        6       1        1
```

goes to this

```
        20191114  20191115 20191116 20191117 20191118
    1     A          B        B       A        A
    2     A          5        6       1        1
```

I'm tried something like this:

```
    df.loc[np.nan, df.columns.weekday not in (4, 5)] = 'A'
    df.loc[np.nan, df.columns.weekday in (4, 5)] = 'B'
```

I tried this in my debugger (PyCharm):

```
    pd.DatetimeIndex(pdf.columns).dayofweek in (4, 5)
```

but that returns

```
    {ValueError}The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I can't seem to get the second term correct. Everything I've seen is talking about datetime values inside of cells but I can't find anything about using column names.

TIA

Comment: `pd.DatetimeIndex(pdf.columns).dayofweek.isin((4,5))`?

Comment: No, that returns the same message.